# Using Facebook Open Graph map aggregation for checkins

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

first of all this is the feature I'm trying to work out:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/

(under the Layout Style heading)

So I've got a cross-platform app which has a feature to allow people to checkin to Facebook Places locations through it. Right now, the actual location publishing works great, but I'm looking to get a little more exposure on peoples' timelines than what we have right now, which is a tiny box saying "Nabil Freeman checked into [location]" in that same small activities pane where it says "Nabil Freeman changed his political views etc.", and an aggregation that literally says "42 checkins" and nothing else.

I really want a map aggregation where instead of highlighting a route, it shows all the pins where Nabil Freeman has checked in the past week, or month, or whatever. A bonus thing to have would be for each checkin to publish a map with a single pin onto the timeline, but the aggregation is a lot more important.

As a bonus, is there any way of embedding my own image into an aggregation? If so, I could construct my own map with Google Maps API or a similar service and just embed that.

Thanks so much for your time guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you described sounds possible using the Open Graph settings of your app.

For example, I made this simple "check-ins" map using a map layout aggregation:

My app's name is "ES1", a test app.

[image: Map layout aggregation of 5 bars reviewed by a user]

This shows placemarks for 5 bars that have been reviewed by a user. The mouse is hovering over "Bar Five" so a label is displayed.  For this, I used the following Open Graph aggregation settings (my object 'bar' has custom properties 'rating' (int) and 'location' (geopoint)):

- Layout style: Map
- Sort by: Custom, bar.rating, Highest to Lowest
- Aggregation title: Review
- Map style: Multiple Actions
- Contributing point: bar.location

For each action ("review"), a story is published. It looks like this:

[image: OG story with map attachment]

The key is to configure a "story attachment" with layout "Map". And to see this map attachment to the story, you have to click the time-based link in the timeline unit. Here's the timeline unit with the time-based link "about a minute ago".

[image: timeline unit of a published action]

My story attachment (part of the action type config) is configured like this:

- Action type: Review
- Connected object: Bar
- [verb tenses go here]
- Attachment layout: Map
- Numbers: bar.rating (number selector), foo (header), points (units)
- Highlighted points: bar.location
- Route: [blank]

Not sure about how you would use your own custom map. Maybe you could create a custom map for each geopoint and save it as a .png then use the .png for og:image.  But the map would not be interactive. Alternatively, just have the page specified by og:url contain the custom map you want.

Comment: Man, thank you!! This looks like exactly what I need. In a few hours I will implement this and post my results here. Looking at what you've shown, I think if I can set the points to be unsorted (since mine have no reviews) this solution is perfect for me.

I do have one more question - do your individual stores get published in the News Feed with a map attached? Not too big a deal if they don't, since the aggregations are the biggest concern for me!

Comment: Donn Lee - I have some problem in this, here everything working fine in my app aggregation. My action type name is 'Checkin'.'Venue' is my object type name. I followed your steps, and i get shared first time. But if i check-in second time it will show like "Sathia checked in 2 venues". If i check-in another venue, it should show like your first image. That means, all locations should show in one map.   I dont know, how to implement this, please help in this.