# Facebook Open Graph: Issue between Old Facebook News Feed and New Facebook News Feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are there issues between the old Facebook News Feed and the new one?

Im getting a conflict between the output of my place open graph collection.

In the old news feed, Im getting this output when doing a cross-platform checkin using Open Graph which I expect to be correct.

[image: aggregation in old news feed]

However in the new Facebook news feed, I got this kind of aggregation. No map is shown and objects are just align in Gallery Layout.

[image: aggregation in new FB news feed]

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990954/using-facebook-open-graph-map-aggregation-for-checkins) which got me a correct result in the old news feed.

Now Im just going in circles here to find a correct fix for the new Facebook News Feed.

**Update**

This is actually a Facebook bug. They are currently working on this, see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/650760744946118?browse=external_tasks_search_results_52675b2424ac31f09052732)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook constantly works on improvements to newsfeed with the goal of making it as relevant as possible for the viewer.  Variations in display are to be expected.  In this case similar actions are being aggregated into a single "story."  This is normal.  From the viewer's standpoint a set of similar stories is often more compelling (and less spammy-feeling) than a bunch of very similar stories.

In other words it is unlikely to be from any error on your side.

Comment: But why is it that other apps such as Path or Foursquare has correct outputs in the news feed both old and new one? Is it because of the special privilege given to them by Facebook? @J Starr